# generic в kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

Хочу сделать клас более гибким при помощи `generics` в `kotlin`. Ранее использовал их только в `java` и в очень примитивных случаях. Перечитал документацию от `jetBrains` но это ясности не дало. Пробовал так:

```
abstract class GraphWrapper<T>(var graphView: GraphView){
...
  private var lineGraphSeries = HashMap<String, T>()
}
```

Как использовать правильно дженерики в котлине?

**UPD:** Вопрос немного изменился. Каким образом возможно создать обьект типа Т?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом плане Kotlin не сильно отличается от Java. В java обычно для этого используют паттерн абстрактная фабрика:

```
interface AbstractFactory<T> {
    fun create(): T
}
```

Реализацию этой фабрики передают объекту который будут внутри созываться объекты нужного типа:

```
abstract class GraphWrapper<T>(var graphView: GraphView, private val factory: AbstractFactory<T>){
...
  private var lineGraphSeries = HashMap<String, T>()

  fun appendNew(alias: String) {
      lineGraphSeries.put(alias, factory.create());
  }
}
```

Либо условливаются, что объекты T обязательно должны содержать конструктор без аргументов и тогда достаточно передать `Class<T> clazz`, у которого для создания экземпляров вызывают `clazz.newInstance()`.